# How to imitate mouse scroll inside div in popup with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

Let's say you have a `<div>` element which appears on a mouse click. Inside of it one has a long list of items cropped by the fixed size of the wrapper. As I understand, setting the `.offsetTop` on the div element would solve this, but I'm trying to do that within puppeteer headless browser by using it's `page.evaluateHandle` method which returns a `JSHandle`. So I'm confused how exactly to achieve the result if I can't get the original element returned by this function. And setting the `offsetTop` inside the callback doesn't make difference, so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

```
  const divHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
    let overflowDiv = document.querySelectorAll(
      `some > selector`
    )[0];
    overflowDiv.offsetTop = overflowDiv.offsetTop + 200
    return overflowDiv.offsetTop;
  });
```

BTW the `.asElement()` also behaves in some unexpected way, I do not completely get it how to try to find an element, get it's absolute position or simply set the parameter.

Additional note: as API docs say regarding the `.evaluateHandle()`:

> ...Function to be evaluated in the page context
>
> ...The only difference between page.evaluate and page.evaluateHandle is that page.evaluateHandle returns in-page object (JSHandle).

**update**
So, to get an element one has to return the JSHandle from `evaluateHandle` method and then pass it as second parameter to `evaluate` method as following:

```
await page.evaluate(e => e, jsHandle);
```

But the main question how to manipulate the attributes, specifically `offsetTop` to imitate scroll remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the answer is very straightforward. I missed the simplest solution with `div.scrollTop = ...`.

```
try {
  const res = await page.$eval(`div._weirdo`,
    e => {
      e.scrollTop = e.scrollTop + 200
      return e
    }
  )
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! Works for me, thanks :)